# Issue with content-type header in Golang ECHO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, echo

I have a simple ECHO application, which is doing some logic and return JSON value. For example :

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:   "web",
        Browse: true,
        HTML5:  true,
    }))
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{echo.OPTIONS, echo.GET, echo.HEAD, echo.PUT, echo.PATCH, echo.POST, echo.DELETE},
    }))

    authenticationRoute := e.Group("")
    authenticationRoute.Register(e.Group("/auth"))

    authenticationRoute .GET("/login", s.loginGet)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}

func loginGet(echo_context echo.Context) error {
    return echo_context.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

On that stage everything is ok, and I get my result.
But when I have tried to use vitejs with ReactJS to have dashboard, unfortunatelly I have empty HTML page with console message :

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1/src/main.jsx” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/plain”)

Can someone please explain how I can dynamically change the "Content-type" header, based on response?
because if I will change everything on "text/javascript", it's just return HTML code
not sure how exaactly should handle it

####### Update 2

Tried to add the header to allowed and add it to response
like :

```
c.Response().Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
```

and

```
AllowHeaders:     []string{"Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-Content-Type-Options"},
```

but no luck

####### Update 3

Found the issue, but don't know still how to fix it.

The ECHO, is able to assign custom headers and it's working. But as I'm importing this file "main.jsx" from HTML code like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The ECHO is ignoring it, and return tsx file in plain text content type header. And how to add it only to it, i don't know